# How to populate list as class object?

Tags: c#, list

How do you populate a list as a class object? For example, this does not work:

```
[DataContract]
public class JsonReviewFormFields
{
    [DataMember]
    public PersonalDevelopmentPlan personalDevelopmentPlan { get; set; }      
}

public class PersonalDevelopmentPlan
{
    public List<ShortTerm> shortTerm { get; set; }
    public List<LongTerm> longTerm { get; set; }
}

public class ShortTerm
{
    public string workRelated { get; set; }
    public string structured { get; set; }
    public string informal   { get; set; }       
    public string reviewDate { get; set; }
}

public class LongTerm
{
    public string workRelated { get; set; }
    public string structured { get; set; }
    public string informal { get; set; }
    public string reviewDate { get; set; }   
}
```

This is controller action:

```
public JsonReviewFormFields GetReviewForm()
{
    PersonalDevelopmentPlan personalDevelopmentPlan = new PersonalDevelopmentPlan();

     List<ShortTerm> _itemsShort = new List<ShortTerm>();
    _itemsShort.Add(new ShortTerm { workRelated = "workRelated text", structured = "structured text", informal = "informal text", reviewDate = "reviewDate" });
    jsonReviewFormFields.personalDevelopmentPlan.shortTerm =  _itemsShort;

    List<LongTerm> _itemsLong = new List<LongTerm>();
    _itemsLong.Add(new LongTerm { workRelated = "workRelated text", structured = "structured text", informal = "informal text", reviewDate = "reviewDate" });
    jsonReviewFormFields.personalDevelopmentPlan.longTerm =  _itemsLong;     

    return jsonReviewFormFields;
}
```

The code crashes at

```
jsonReviewFormFields.personalDevelopmentPlan.shortTerm =  _itemsShort;
```

It's probably a basic object orientated error. How do you populate the list?

Comment: can you add the crash log or error message?

Comment: Where is `jsonReviewFormFields` defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not instantiating it, you have to instantiated the type first:

```
jsonReviewFormFields.personalDevelopmentPlan = new PersonalDevelopmentPlan();
```

and then set property of it:

```
jsonReviewFormFields.personalDevelopmentPlan.shortTerm =  _itemsShort
```

before that you also have to instantiate main class which i don't see in your controller action anywhere :

```
JsonReviewFormFields jsonReviewFormFields = new JsonReviewFormFields();
```

Comment: JsonReviewFormFields jsonReviewFormFields = new JsonReviewFormFields();

Comment: Ehsan, forgot to include in the code above. All is now good, ta